# c# Sorted List in Function

Tags: c#, console-application

hi i want to make a sorted list in ShowSort function it shows randomly i want to sort numbers from smallest to largest pls help

```
private static void hatekleme(List<Hat> hatlar)
 {
   List<Islem> islem1 = new List<Islem>();
   islem1.Add(new Islem { Id = 1, Name = "tv ekranı", Time = 0, Time1 = 0, Time2 = 0, Time3 = 0 });
   islem1.Add(new Islem { Id = 2, Name = "tv kasası ", Time = 0, Time1 = 0, Time2 = 0, Time3 = 0 });
   islem1.Add(new Islem { Id = 3, Name = "tv vidas", Time = 0, Time1 = 0, Time2 = 0, Time3 = 0 });

   List<Islem> islem2 = new List<Islem>();
   islem2.Add(new Islem { Id = 1, Name = "işlemci  ", Time = 0, Time1 = 0, Time2 = 0, Time3 = 0 });
   islem2.Add(new Islem { Id = 2, Name = "ram", Time = 0, Time1 = 0, Time2 = 0, Time3 = 0 });
   islem2.Add(new Islem { Id = 3, Name = "gpu", Time = 0, Time1 = 0, Time2 = 0, Time3 = 0 });

   hatlar.Add(new Hat { Id = 1, Name = "Tv Üretim Hattı", Islemler = islem1 });
   hatlar.Add(new Hat { Id = 2, Name = "Anakart üretim hattı", Islemler = islem2 });

 }

private static void ShowSort(Hat category)
 {
   foreach (var product in category.Islemler)
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"{product.Name} : {product.Time} sn.");
    }
     Console.WriteLine("");
  }
```

Comment: See what you can do first with `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=net-6.0. Instead of using `List<TValue>`, try to see if you can use that class to store your objects so that your collection is directly sorted by key when you print the output in your console.

Comment: i look but i cant thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily sort items in a list by OrderBy:

```
private static void ShowSort(Hat category)
        {
            var sortedItems=category.Islemler.OrderBy(x => x.Time);
            foreach (var product in sortedItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{product.Name} : {product.Time} sn.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
```